# Unpacking arguments of a functional parameter to a C++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a question involving functional template arguments to template classes in C++.

I'd like to define a template class `Foo` taking a single template parameter `Fun`

```
   template <typename Fun>
   struct Foo {
      ...
   };
```

such that given a function like

```
   void bar(std::string a, float b, char c)
   {
      ...
   }
```

then `Foo<bar>::args_t` will be equivalent to a typedef for

```
   std::tuple<std::string, float, char>
```

Is this possible?  (The use of `std::tuple` here is just for concreteness.  More generally I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like pattern-matching on the arguments of a functional template parameter.)

The point is to avoid having to define `Foo` in a way like

```
   template Foo<typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D,
      D (*Fun)(A a, B b, C c)>
   struct Foo {
      typedef std::tuple<A,B,C>  args_t;
   };
```

which requires both committing to a fixed number of function arguments, and requiring the argument and return types of the function to be provided explicitly as template parameters.  (Defining `Foo` using variadic templates could presumably solve the former issue, but what about the latter?)

Thanks!

Comment: Look into variadic templates. Also you might want to avoid naming types with `_t` as they are reserved in POSIX.

Comment: @user657267 I'm quite aware of variadic templates, and mentioned them in my question.  The comment about naming types with `_t` seems to be a bit out of left field.

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Declare a primary template and leave it unimplemented.

```
template<typename T>
struct foo;     // unimplemented primary template
```

Then provide a partial specialization that matches function types as the template argument.

```
template<typename Result, typename... Args>
struct foo<Result(Args...)>
{
    using args_t = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
```

You can access the nested type as

```
foo<decltype(bar)>::args_t
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a036b414602e237)

Comment: Great, `decltype` seems to be the key here, thanks very much!