# Extracting function argument types as a parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, variadic-templates

This is a followup question to ["unpacking" a tuple to call a matching function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer), which asked how to provide the values from a `std::tuple` as arguments to a function in a generic way.  A solution given there was the following:

```
template<int ...>
struct seq { };

template<int N, int ...S>
struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> { };

template<int ...S>
struct gens<0, S...>
{
   typedef seq<S...> type;
};

double foo(int x, float y, double z)
{
   return x + y + z;
}

template <typename... Args>
struct save_it_for_later
{
   std::tuple<Args...> params;
   double (*func)(Args...);

   double delayed_dispatch()
   {
    return callFunc(typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
   }

   template<int ...S>
   double callFunc(seq<S...>)
   {
    return func(std::get<S>(params) ...);
   }
};

int main(void)
{
   std::tuple<int, float, double> t = std::make_tuple(1, 1.2, 5);
   save_it_for_later<int,float, double> saved = {t, foo};
   std::cout << saved.delayed_dispatch() << std::endl;
}
```

My question is whether there's way to make an alternate version of `save_it_for_later` which takes only `foo` as a template argument, so that we don't have to provide `foo` 's parameter types as a template argument (or bake its return type into `save_it_for_later`).  Something like

```
int main(void) {
   ...
   save_it_for_later2<foo> saved = {t};
   ...
}
```

I'd be equally fine with some sort of macro wrapping `foo` to extract the required types:

```
int main(void) {
   ...
   save_it_for_later<MACRO_USING_DECLTYPE_OR_SOMESUCH(foo)> saved = {t};
   ...
}
```

This concern seems orthogonal enough to the original question to warrant its own ticket.

Comment: What is `foo`? If it's a general functor with multiple overloads of `operator()`, which overload should you use? If `foo` is going to be, for example, just a function pointer or `std::function`, this is easy to do. The general case is hard.

Comment: `foo` is just a function pointer, as in the example above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename> struct save_it_for_later_t;
template <typename Result, typename... Args>
struct save_it_for_later_t<Result (*)(Args...)> {
    std::tuple<Args...>   params;
    Result              (*fun)(Args...);
    template <typename... Params>
    save_it_for_later_t(Result (*fun)(Args...), Params&&... params)
        : params(std::forward<Params>(params)...)
        , fun(fun) {
    }
    // ... 
};
template <typename Result, typename... Args, typename... Params>
save_it_for_later_t<Result(*)(Args...)>
save_it_for_later(Result (*fun)(Args...), Params&&... params) {
    return save_it_for_later_t<Result(*)(Args...)>(fun, std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}

double foo(float, float, double);
int main() {
    auto saved = save_it_for_later(foo, 1.2f, 3.4f, 5.6);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great!  For bonus points, is it possible to make `foo` itself a template parameter (rather than a class member)?  Long story, but in my situation---which is different than the artificial example above---this would actually be incredibly useful.

Comment: Actually, before getting to the bonus points, your solution doesn't seem quite right; can you provide a full solution which you've checked compiles?

Comment: @factotum: yes, there were a few minor typos. These are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I just sheepishly discovered that I'd asked a similar question last year ([Unpacking arguments of a functional parameter to a C++ template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948277/unpacking-arguments-of-a-functional-parameter-to-a-c-template-class)), which yields an answer here too:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<int ...>
struct seq { };

template<int N, int ...S>
struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> { };

template<int ...S>
struct gens<0, S...>
{
   typedef seq<S...> type;
};

double foo(int x, float y, double z)
{
   return x + y + z;
}

template<typename T>
struct save_it_for_later;

template <typename Result, typename... Args>
struct save_it_for_later<Result(Args...)>
{
   std::tuple<Args...> params;
   Result (*func)(Args...);

   Result delayed_dispatch()
   {
    return callFunc(typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
   }

   template<int ...S>
   Result callFunc(seq<S...>)
   {
    return func(std::get<S>(params) ...);
   }
};

int main(void)
{
   std::tuple<int, float, double> t = std::make_tuple(1, 1.2, 5);
   save_it_for_later<decltype(foo)> saved = {t, foo};
   std::cout << saved.delayed_dispatch() << std::endl;
}
```