# How to static_assert to check function signature is correct

Tags: c++, static-assert, compile-time-type-checking

### The Code

I have a templated type that follows the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

```
template <typename T>
class Subject {
public:
    template <template<typename> typename Observer>
    void AddObserver(Observer<T>& observer)
    {
        observers.push_back([&](const T& value) { observer.OnEvent(value); });
    }

    void Event(const T& value) const
    {
        for (auto& o : observers) { 
            o.OnEvent(value) 
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(const T&)>> observers;
};
```

The above works great but only so long as the `Observer` is a templated type. So I can modify the template signature and accept any type, regardless of whether they are templated.

```
    template <typename Observer>
    void AddObserver(Observer& observer)
    {
        observers.push_back([&](const T& value) { observer.OnEvent(value); });
    }
```

---

### The Issue

But now there aren't any compile time checks on type matching between the Subject and the Observer. (**EDIT** it has been pointed out that there is no guarantee that `Observer<T>` actually uses `T` in its `OnEvent` function signature)

I'd like to add a static cast to the function that checks that the two types `Subject<**T**>` and the `Observer::OnEvent(const **T**&)` are the same, to prevent automagic type conversions. Something like the below.

```
static_cast(std::is_same<T, **type_of_first_param**(Observer::OnEvent)>::value, "Subject/Observer type mistatch.");
```

---

### Possible approach that I need help with

If I cannot extract the type from the function signature, perhaps I can construct a function signature to which I can compare it?

```
static_cast(std::is_same<**Observer::MadeUpFunc(const T&)**, Observer::OnEvent>::value, "Subject/Observer type mistatch.");
```

I'm investigating [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31539364/921224), and I'm pretty sure it holds the answer I need, just need some time and perhaps guidance to figure it out.

I have tried the following, but get the compile time error

> typename specifier refers to non-type member 'OnEvent' in 'Observer'

```
static_assert(std::is_same<typename Observer::OnEvent, void (Observer::*)(const T&...)>::value, "");
```

---

### What I have tried

- I have read the documentation here [cppreference.com/w/cpp/types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types)
- I have read some of the documentation here [cppreference.com/w/cpp/language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language), namely the sections under **Functions** and **Templates**
- I have read this [drdobbs.com/cpp/extracting-function-parameter-and-return](https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/extracting-function-parameter-and-return/240000586)
- I have looked at these *similar* QAs [Extracting function argument types as a parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30926764/921224), [“unpacking” a tuple to call a matching function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7858817/921224)

---

Comment: Good spot, I accidentally referred to `Observer` as `Listener`, will fix

Comment: It is not fully clear to me why how your first example and your second example should be different regarding the `observers.push_back([&](const T& value) { observer.OnEvent(value); });` part.

Comment: @t.niese in the first example there is complile time type enforcement, any `Observer<T>` and `Subject<T>` had to have matching `T`, in the second, `T` may be different, so long as the compiler is happy with an implicit conversion, which I'd like to prevent.

Comment: Yes but how does the first one ensure that `OnEvent` has a parameter that matches `T`, that would only be the case if the templated class uses its template for the parameter of `OnEvent`.

Comment: @t.niese This is true, I am happy that in our code base that the template type and the function signature will always match, the need for the assert is to help muppets like me notice when we have hooked up mismatching `Subject`s and `Observer`s. Your point basically just means that whatever assert we come up with be useful in both functions.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to be sure that I understand it correctly, that the problem also persists in the first example.

Comment: You already demand that `Observer` has a function `OnEvent(OtherT value)`. Why not also demand a typename: `using EventArg = OtherT`, and then using `static_assert<std::is_same_v<T, typename Observer::EventArg > >`?

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765/1023911?

Comment: @BennyK I'm not sure I understand how you're specifying or extracting `OtherT`, the asert is exactly what I want but `OtherT` isn't obviously available in this context

Comment: @Troyseph That's what the `using` statement is for

Comment: The point is if you require `template<typename T> struct Observer { void OnEvent(T e) {}};`, then you also could require `struct Observer {using  EventArg = SomeType;  void OnEvent(EventArg e) {}]` and you could check against `Observer::EventArg`, it would have the same reliability as your first example. But for sure not the required reliability you are asking for. This `using  EventArg = SomeType; ` exists in many places in the std library (and others too) to get information about certain types of a class (e.g. `value_type', `allocator_type`, `size_type`, … in `std::vector`).

Comment: @t.niese It would have better reliability than in the first example. The only possible problem is that the definition of `OnEvent` may use a type different from `EventArg`, but for that to happen the user will have to be somewhat malicious.

Comment: @BennyK in both cases the user could do `template<typename T> struct Observer { void OnEvent(SomeOtherType e) {}};` or `struct Observer {using  EventArg = SomeType;  void OnEvent(SomeOtherType e) {}};`, I don't see much of a difference there. In both cases you don't know the type of the argument of `OnEvent` and need to rely in the user to do it correctly.

Comment: @t.niese That's exactly what I said. The added reliability is in the fact that `template<typename T> struct Observer { void OnEvent(SomeOtherType e) {}};` may be an innocent mistake, and `struct Observer {using  EventArg = SomeType;  void OnEvent(SomeOtherType e) {}};` is less likely to be innocent.

Comment: @BennyK I don't agree with that - but that's opinion based - because normally you would name it like this `template<typename EventArg> struct Observer`, so it should be equivalent. Anyhow the `using  EventArg = SomeType;` approach is so common in various libraries, that I would use that one, because you don't limit your self to the function signature.

Comment: @t.niese Why is the function signature limiting? Or rather, why is that limitation bad? As far as I see, it is exactly the limitation I want, and doesn't rely on implementors remembering to correctly add additional boilerplate to each `Observer` type.

Comment: @Troyseph in this particular case it might not be a problem. I can't make up an example right now, but there can be situations for which you want to get the actual type of the argument or another type of the class. And defining that a class has to have a clear interface providing one or many `using sometype_t = its_actual_type;` and use them accordingly, makes many things easier and consistent.

Comment: @Troyseph in case of events, you could imagine, that you have an inheritance for the events, like `MouseEvent : Event`, `MouseMoveEvent : MouseEvent`, and  you could require, that the `OnEvent` consumes at least `MouseEvent` but not `Event`. Then the `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(&Observer::OnEvent), void (Observer::*)(const T&) const>)` would not work. This might also be some kind of a strange made up example, but I'm not able to come up with a better one right now.

Comment: @t.niese Fair, in my case event types are always builtin types or `POD`s, but I can see how event type inheritance might muddy the water, I suppose in @mpark's answer, the solution would be to substitute `is_same` for something that allows for inheritance?

Comment: @Troyseph as I said, I can't come up with an example right now for which one can't discuss other solutions and whether it is possible to retrieve that type in this case or not. My point was just, that using the technique that is present in the std library and others where types of interest are exposed using the `using some_type_t = its_acutal_type` syntax, helps to get around many headaches and to keep things consistent ;). And because you can use those `some_type_t` in your member function signatures and bodies it can make things more maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what restrictions you want here.
The most restrictive would be to enforce something like:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(&Observer::OnEvent),
                             void (Observer::*)(const T&) const>);
```

where the `OnEvent` function couldn't be a `template`, it couldn't return anything aside from `void`, it would be required to be marked `const`, and it would have to take `const T&`, even if `T` is `int`.

Comment: Ah, I was just investigating decltype! Will try this out

Comment: My final code uses `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(&Observer::OnEvent), void (Observer::*)(const T&...) const>);` with the only difference being that my real world code has a variadic `Subject` template. Very nice answer thank you, much simpler than all of the SFINAE options I was investigating, that required making multiple additional templated types.