# Type of member functions arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, decltype, member-functions

Using C++11 I am trying to get the type of function arguments from a function name, granted the function signature is unambiguous. Ultimately, I am trying to check that an argument is exactly the type I want *before* I call a function.

So far I can do it with non-member functions thanks to this solution: 
[Unpacking arguments of a functional parameter to a C++ template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948277/unpacking-arguments-of-a-functional-parameter-to-a-c-template-class#24948381)

I have slightly edited it to get the following class:

```
template<typename T>
struct FunctionSignatureParser; // unimplemented primary template
template<typename Result, typename...Args>
struct FunctionSignatureParser<Result(Args...)>
{
    using return_type = Result;
    using args_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
    template <size_t i> struct arg
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, args_tuple>::type type;
    };
};
```

For instance I can check the type of a function at compile-time:

```
short square(char x) { // 8-bit integer as input, 16-bit integer as output
    return short(x)*short(x);
}
int main() {
        char answer = 42;
        static_assert(std::is_same<char, FunctionSignatureParser<decltype(square)>::arg<0>::type>::value, "Function 'square' does not use an argument of type 'char'");
        static_assert(std::is_same<short, FunctionSignatureParser<decltype(square)>::return_type>::value, "Function 'square' does not return a value of type 'short'");
        short sqrAnswer = square(answer);
        std::cout << "The square of " << +answer << " is " << +sqrAnswer << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

[>> Online code with gcc](https://ideone.com/6JV52t)

But when I want to check the type of member functions, some compilers are not happy with it:

```
struct Temperature
{
    double degrees;
    Temperature add(double value);
};
int main() {
    Temperature t{16};
    double increment{8};
    static_assert(std::is_same<double, FunctionSignatureParser<decltype(t.add)>::arg<0>::type>::value, "Method 'Temperature::add' does not use an argument of type 'double'");
    std::cout << t.degrees << u8" \u00b0C + " << increment << " == " << t.add(increment).degrees << u8" \u00b0C" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what gcc 6.3 has to say:

> error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘Temperature Temperature::add(double)’

[>> Online code with gcc](https://ideone.com/hUAT61)

Here is what clang 4.0 has to say:

> error: reference to non-static member function must be called

[>> Online code with clang](https://ideone.com/zjBJnC)

I have tried those options, to no avail:

```
decltype(Temperature::add)
decltype(std::declval<Temperature>().add)
```

What’s the problem with non-static member functions inside a `decltype`? Since expressions inside a `decltype` are not evaluated, the `static` qualifier should not matter, right?

For the record, MSVC12 succeeds in this situation. I cannot tell if the Microsoft compiler is right or wrong, though. (please let’s not make this thread a compiler war)

Also, if you have a solution to argument checking that does not involve the initial approach, I am open for it as well.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38457112/2642059

Comment: I wouldn't use MSVC12 as a paragon of standards conformance. Can you test again in the 15.5 compiler (VS2017.5)?

Comment: @Mgetz I agree MSVC12 is not ideal but currently that’s the most recent version I can get my hands on, thus I cannot test with 15.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need another template specialization for member functions, something like this:

```
template<typename ClassType, typename Result, typename...Args>
struct FunctionSignatureParser<Result(ClassType::*)(Args...)>
{
    using return_type = Result;
    using args_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
    template <size_t i> struct arg
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, args_tuple>::type type;
    };
};
```

And it can be used like this:

```
    static_assert(std::is_same<double, FunctionSignatureParser<decltype(&Temperature::add)>::arg<0>::type>::value, "Method 'Temperature::add' does not use an argument of type 'double'");
```

This works with gcc 7.2, haven't tested other compilers

Comment: This works like a charm with gcc 6.3, clang 4.0 and MSVC12. Many thanks, @dvk. I still do not understand why clang and gcc reject non-static member functions but this is secondary since the solution fully solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following dvk's answer, here is a little improvement that handles the case where the member function is `const`. A base class can be defined in order to avoid code duplication.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename Result, typename ...Args>  struct FunctionSignatureParserBase
{
    using return_type = Result;
    using args_tuple  = std::tuple<Args...>;
    template <size_t i> struct arg
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, args_tuple>::type type;
    };

    template <size_t i>  using arg_t = typename arg<i>::type;
};

template<typename T>  struct FunctionSignatureParser;

template<typename ClassType, typename Result, typename...Args>
struct FunctionSignatureParser<Result(ClassType::*)(Args...)>
  : FunctionSignatureParserBase<Result,Args...>
{
};

template<typename ClassType, typename Result, typename...Args>
struct FunctionSignatureParser<Result(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
  : FunctionSignatureParserBase<Result,Args...>
{
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct foo { void operator() (int n)       {}  };
struct bar { void operator() (int n) const {}  };

using foo_t = typename FunctionSignatureParser<decltype(&foo::operator())>::arg_t<0>;
using bar_t = typename FunctionSignatureParser<decltype(&bar::operator())>::arg_t<0>;

static_assert(std::is_same<int, foo_t>::value == true);
static_assert(std::is_same<int, bar_t>::value == true);

int main() {}
```